# How to plot a bifurcation diagram of a multi dimensional system in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

I have a question regarding the following Maxwell-Bloch equations:

> dE/dt =-0.1*E + 0.25*P
>
> dP/dt = -P+0.8*E*D
>
> dD/dt = -4*(D-Lambda)+E*P

How can I plot the bifurcation diagram of this multi dimensional system in MATLAB. Is is possible plot this for multiple values of lambda?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8382-chaotic-generators-demo?